# How to solve an implicit differentiation while there are two expressions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, implicit-differentiation

I have this problem:

> if $$u=x^3y$$ then calculate $du/dt$ while $$x^5 + y =t$$ and $$x^2 + y^3 = t^2$$

I know that I should use the chain rule, and solved the problem to this point: $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{du}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 3x^2y$$
$$\frac{du}{dy} = x^3$$

Differentiation of the first expression with respect to $t$:
$$5x^4\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} = 1$$

Differentiation of the second expression with respect to $t$:
$$2x\frac{dx}{dt} + 3y^2\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t$$

But I don't know what should I do now, should I substitute something or what? I dont know what should I exactly do when we have an implicit Differentiation with two or three expressions. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can from the last two equations determine $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and plug these into your first equation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks, but if I, for example what to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ then I would have two of it, one for the first equation, one for the second, should I equit the two equations, to get one of then?

Comment: Of course you wouldn't have two of it: two equations, two unknowns is usually solvable isn't it?

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, it is, thank you very very much.